# I'm not getting the expected result from `truncnorm::rtruncnorm()`

Tags: r

I'm not getting the expected result from `truncnorm::rtruncnorm()`. I expect the mean to be around `24.5` and the sd to be around `10.7`, but I'm getting different values. Are these impossible values given the parameters, or is this a problem with `truncnorm::rtruncnorm()`? Is there a better way to draw a distribution with these parameters?

```
library(truncnorm)
set.seed(231940293)
x <- rtruncnorm(10000, a=10, b=63, mean=24.5, sd=10.7)
mean(x)
# 26.4351
sd(x)
# 9.02587
```

Comment: I'm not the author (and I haven't looked at the code in detail), but my guess is that the `mean=` and `sd=` parameters are for the underlying (canonical) normal distribution. Once you convert a normal distribution into an asymmetric distribution, I no longer expect the empirical statistics to preserve the expectations. (But this is just a guess.)

Comment: Related is a github issue dated May 2019: https://github.com/olafmersmann/truncnorm/issues/4. (Currently no reply to it.)

Comment: Ah ok. Happen to know about other solutions?

Comment: Nope ... though I did look at wiki's page on [truncate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution), and it generally agrees that its mean/deviation are based on the canonical normal distribution. The more I think about it, I am confused about how to interpret your request. I think you're wanting to *"create a truncated-normal random sample with input-mean `mu1`, input-sd `sigma1`, bounds `a` and `b`, and with an actual sample mean/sd of `mu2` and `sigma2`"*. You're taking the mean of a trunc'd/skew'd norm distribution, I think `mu1=mu2` is highly unlikely.

Comment: (I might be wrong ... in which case this might be better informed on [math.se] or [stats.se].)

Comment: Thanks @r2evans. I'm trying to simulate some data with a possible range of 10-63 where the mean of the *generated data* is 24.5 and the sd is 10.7.

Comment: I think the statistics' equations listed on the wiki site I linked look about right. I don't know of a closed-form solution to define the mu/sigma you *want*; all of the equations are based on mu and sigma from the canonical, which means you need to reverse a lot in order to find what you need. Another approach might be to `optimize` or `optim` a smaller distribution sample to get the empiric stats you want, and then expand it to the size you need with the determined parameters. I don't know that this method contains much mathematic *rigor*, but it might suffice.

Comment: (Sorry, Eric, I don't think I'm going to give you a viable/quick answer. I do not know of any implementation that "does what you want and does it *right*", but I have not searched extensively. This is math-heavy, though, so ... it might also be obscure and hard-to-find ... if it even exists.)

Comment: Ok I appreciate your help